# How to compute the pointwise stabilizer subgroup of a fixed-point subspace?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, gap, sagemath

*Definitions*: Let $W$ be a representation of a group $G$, $K$ a subgroup of $G$, and $X$ a subspace of $W$.
 Let the *fixed-point subspace* $W^{K}:=\{w \in W \ \vert \  kw=w \ , \forall k \in K  \}$.
Let the *pointwise stabilizer subgroup* $G_{(X)}:=\{ g \in G \  \vert \ gx=x \ , \forall x \in X \}$.

Let $G$ be a finite group, $H$ a subgroup and $V$ an irreducible complex representation of $G$.

**Question**: How to compute $G_{(V^H)}$?

*Remark*: It's for doing checks about [this problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/201218/34538).

Comment: @DerekHolt:  I don't think so. $V$ is an irreducible representation of $G$, but in general $0≠V^H⊊V$, so the subspace $V^H$ is not stable by the action of $G$, it's not a subrepresentation of $G$. Moreover $H⊂G_{(V^H)}⊂G$.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your notation. For some reason I was thinking that $V^H$ was an induced module, but I hadn't read the question carefully enough. It could be that there nothing better than standard Stabilizer algorithms.

Comment: @DerekHolt: Yes, but before computing $G_{(V^H)}$, one needs to compute $V^H$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are basically two steps, first computing $V^H$ and then computing the stabilizer.

$V^H$ is simply the common eigenspace of $K$ for eigenvalue 1. We get this by intersecting the eigenspaces of the generators. Thus (One could go to formal vector spaces, but staying in the matrix world is less typing):

```
eig:=List(GeneratorsOfGroup(K),x->NullspaceMat(x-x^0));
ise:=eig[1];
for i in eig do ise:=SumIntersectionMat(ise,i)[2];od;
```

Now `ise` is a basis for $V^H$. To stabilize the space, as Derek already wrote, I cannot think of something better in the generic case than a naive orbit-stabilizer calculation. Take the vectors in use, and stabilize them in turn:

```
stb:=G;
for i in ise do
  stb:=Stabilizer(G,i,OnRight);
od;
```

If you instead want to stabilize the space as a *set*, represent it by its RREF basis:

```
ise:=TriangulizedMat(ise);
stb:=Stabilizer(G,ise,OnSubspacesByCanonicalBasis);;
```

(This implicitly enumerates the orbit, so if your stabilizer has large index this is costly.)

Comment: Since we know that the stabilizer contains $H$, if $H$ is already a "large" subgroup, then another option might be to compute the minimal overgroups of $H$, check whether any of them stabilize the subspace pointwise, and repeat if necessary.

Comment: There is a problem: `Stabilizer(G,ise,OnSubspacesByCanonicalBasis)` is not the *pointwise* stabilizer as expected by the definition $G_{(X)}:=\{ g \in G \  \vert \ gx=x \ , \forall x \in X \}$, your function corresponds to the other stabilizer $G_{X}:=\{ g \in G \  \vert \ gX=X  \}$.

Comment: @SébastienPalcoux Sorry -- misread the question, as people usually want the setwise stabilizer. I've edited the answer.